# How to obtain a nested average with Dax in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to calculate the average of a column in a measure in DAX, but I have the problem that the values are duplicated on multiple rows.

The data looks like this:

```
Line  ID  Value
1     1   10
2     1   10
3     1   10
4     1   10
5     1   10
6     2   40
7     2   40
8     3   90
9     3   90
10    3   90
```

When I do

`sum(data[Value]) / countrows(data)`

the answer will be (50 + 80 + 270) / 10 = 40.

However, I want the answer to be (10 + 40 + 90) / 3 = 46.7

I know I have to divide by 3 and can achieve the 3 by

`distinctcount(data[ID])`

But I find it difficult to extract the 10, 40 and 90.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that. For example:

```
Average Value =
  VAR Summarized_Table = SUMMARIZE ( Data, Data[ID], Data[Value] )
  VAR Total_Value = SUMX ( Summarized_Table, Data[Value] )
  VAR Total_Count = COUNTROWS ( Summarized_Table )
  RETURN
    DIVIDE ( Total_Value, Total_Count )
```

Result:

[image]

Explanation:

- First, we create a summarized version of the data, by grouping it on ID and Value columns. Grouping eliminates duplication, so the summary table contains only 3 records. We save the table in a variable;
- Second, we sum up values in the summary table (140);
- Third, we count number of records in the summary table (3)
- Finally, we return the result by dividing sum and count

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
Average Value =
  AVERAGEX ( VALUES ( Data[ID] ), CALCULATE ( AVERAGE ( Data[Value] ) ) )
```

Result is the same, but the logic is different:

- First, using VALUES we create a list of distinct IDs;
- Second, we use AVERAGEX to iterate the list, and for each ID calculate its average value. For example, for ID=1, result will be Average of (50)/5= 10;
- Finally, we average the averages as (10 + 40 + 90) / 3